# App to block data usage on iphone

Tags: iphone, software-recommendation

I was wondering if it was possible to block data usage completely when a certain data transfer limit has been reached? Does an app exist for that?

I am aware there are some apps that allow users to view the data usage, but is there an app to prevent completely from using Data when limit is exceeded, automatically?! This would be especially usefull to prevent the extra fees when exceeding my 1GB data usage limit.

Comment: Anybody heard of or tried an app called "my data manager"?

Answer (score 1):

No, that is not possible: it would mean Apple allows developers access to deactivating data access. I guess you can understand the security problem that would mean: an app could decide on its own you don't have data access anymore.

The only way to do that is to regularly check your data usage in “Settings > General > Usage > Cell network usage” (menu names may not be the exact ones, my iPhone isn't in English, sorry). You can reinitialize these statistics each time your limit is reset.

If your limit is crossed, switch data off in “Settings > Network” (iOS 5 only).

Answer (score 1):

If you are jailbroken, there are some features around the SBSettings app - you can certainly make it very easy both to see how much data has gone past and switch it with a toggle - it's entirely possible that this could happen automatically...

Answer (score 1):

you can use "[data usage](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/data-usage/id386950560?mt=8)" app  it will notify you when you achieve certain amount of data and then if you reach your desired amount, in your ios device go to:
settings > Network > cellular data > OFF

Comment: Correct +1 and also Flight mode works although not suitable here unless wanting to cut all connections.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't anything to do with the iPhone, but almost all providers will be willing to stop you going over your limit. Just ask them, it'd be easier than a software based solution on your side.

Comment: Most providers are after your money, and I can tell you they are very happy to silently put you on the expensive per MB prices when you exceed your limit, with no intentions of changing that.

Answer (score 0):

You could download an app like [Bytes](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/bytes/id909295797?mt=8&at=10lJ7Y&ct=StackOverflow) that allows you to track your data use and receive notifications when you reach your limit.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is possible, and you can set a hard cap on data use. If you are in the USA and have Verizon, you can sign up for their [Family Base](http://www.familybase.vzw.com/) app.

As of 2016, Verizon charge $5/mo ($60/year) for this service. Family Base will let you set alerts and caps for *each* phone on your account. For instance, I share my account with my data-hogging teenager. After he blew through all my data 2 months in a row, I capped him at half of our shared data allowance using Family Base. He now uses up his half of the data in a week to 10 days, but I get to keep my half, and I don't feel guilty about it at all.